# Xcode run code and black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, screen

I have a problem.

I write code in button touch event. Run project and click button. Then i get a black screen.

```
- (IBAction)ff:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Add button in XIB or Storyboard.

**2)** Create a button in your `viewController.h` file

```
__weak IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;
```

**3)** In the same file, add selector of the button:

```
-(IBAction)yourButton_pressed:(id)sender;
```

**4)** Go to XIB or Storyboard, open `Connection Inspector`, Drag and drop from `yourButton` to the button added in XIB or Storyboard.

**5)** Same way, Drag and drop from `yourButton_pressed` to the button added in XIB or Storyboard. It will ask you for the action type like `TouchUpInside`, `TouchUpOutside`. Select `TouchUpInside` for now.

**6)**  Present modal view controller:

```
YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourView" bundle:nil];
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

**7)** Enjoy and Upvote  :D

Answer (score 0):

Just select the Button from the MainStoryboard and hold CTRL and drag it to the view controller and select present modally.
And remove the IBAction from the implementation and remove the sent events from the MainStoryboard for that button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to SecondViewController, you can always use **prepareForSegue** method.

But first make a connection, see screenshots here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdC86.jpg

Then add this code to your viewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSecondVC"]) {
        SecondViewController *secondVC = [segue destinationViewController]; 
    }
}
```